# How to properly getItem with AsyncStorage in React Native?

Tags: ios, facebook, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

My current project require me to store user data locally, So I use the AsyncStorage from react native itself. However I got some issues on how to retrieve already saved data I always get null but somehow the data is saved..

I always get

> { _45: 0, _81: 0, _65: null, _54: null }

and here's my code, which is the simple example from react native documentation

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('baru', 'this is new dude!!');
var b = AsyncStorage.getItem('baru');
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading the docs of [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html):

> static getItem(key, callback?) 
>   Fetches an item for a key and invokes a callback upon completion. Returns a Promise object.

You need to handle that promise. I'd recommend you to use (as the docs) `async/await`. So for example you can do:

```
async function getItem(item) {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(item);
    console.log(value);
    return value;
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle errors here
  }
}
```

You should actually do something similar for `setItem` too.

Comment: `AsynchStorage` is deprecated now. I found a problem with the new method.[https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-async-storage](react-native-community/react-native-async-storage). Above `getItem` method is not working for me.